# auto width div boxes

Tags: html, width, percentage

This has possibly been answered a couple of times before but I just can't find this answer to my specific problem.

I've been working on this: http://jsfiddle.net/LPGGh/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="project">
    <div class="media"></div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="project">
    <div class="media"></div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="project">
    <div class="media"></div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

```
.media{
width: 300px;
height:200px;
background-color:red;
margin-bottom:1em;
}

.text{
margin-bottom:2em;
}

.project{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 1em;
margin-right: 1em;
}

.wrapper{
margin-top: 1.65em;
width: 100%;
}
```

**My question is how I get the .media to auto fit in width so the red boxes always uses all of the space available and still keep the margins of course?**

Thanks!

Comment: do you want the red boxes in the same row or stacked on top of each other?

Comment: In the same row. I think the boxes should have some sort of min-width maybe. Example: When the box goes under width 20% for example it jumps down to the next row having two boxes instead of three in a row. I hope you understand :-)

Comment: and where do you want the text?

Comment: The text should always be under the red box as in the jsfiddle I did

Comment: I gave it one my try and actually almost did it: http://jsfiddle.net/LPGGh/15/

I just need to adjust the min-width I think :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used your fiddle, so the names are a little different in my answer.

Here is a solution by creating a wrapper for the media element:

```
<div class="project_container_parent">
    <div class="project_container_child">
        <div class="media_parent"><div class="media"></div></div>
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project_container_child">
        <div class="media_parent"><div class="media"></div></div>
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project_container_child">
        <div class="media_parent"><div class="media"></div></div>
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And setting the css like this:

```
.media{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

.media_parent{
    margin-left:1em;
    margin-right:1em;    
}

.text{
    margin-bottom:2em;
}

.project_container_child{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.project_container_parent{
    margin-top: 1.65em;
}
```

Here is your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LPGGh/13/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but that's not what I'm looking for.

For example: If you have two of the boxes aligned on one row with a bit of extra white space on the right (use my fiddle to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/LPGGh/) I want them to auto fit in width filling all of this white space.